# Extract data from an XML object

Tags: php, simplexml

How do i extract the data from that xml object which is a value of a certain array:

```
Array ( [Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[0] => The Key of Life; A Metaphysical Investigation ) 
[ASIN] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0982385099 ) ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract data from an XML object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917998/extract-data-from-an-xml-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do string typecasting of the object.

$variable = (string) $FieldValue[0];

That would work, as SimpleXml has all the children in object type and not string.

Answer (score 0):

say $X is the object, so to print

> The Key of Life; A Metaphysical
>   Investigation

you do:

```
echo $X->Title[0]
```

Comment: i did a for each of the array like: foreach( $ArrayName as $FieldLabel => $FieldValue ){ $Variable = $FieldValue[0].... } but still it gets the whole xml object as the fieldvalue.. I wanted it to extract the value only not the whole object..

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that you're not working with an array — you're working with a SimpleXMLElement object, which is not the same.

1. Instead of doing `$array['key']['subkey']`, you would do `$xml->tag->subtag`.
2. SimpleXML nodes are not strings or arrays, although they behave string-like and array-like. Make sure you always typecast the value to an explicit string.
3. If you're accessing the first node, you don't need to use `[0]`. It's assumed.
4. You can convert SimpleXMLElement objects into true associative arrays in PHP 5.2 or newer with:

   `$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);`