# Extract data from an XML object

Tags: php, simplexml

How do I extract the data from that XML object, which is a value of a certain array:

```
Array ( 
   [Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
      [0] => The Key of Life; A Metaphysical Investigation 
    ) 
   [ASIN] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0982385099 ) ...
 )
```

I did a `foreach` of the array like:

```
foreach ($ArrayName as $FieldLabel => $FieldValue) { 
     $Variable = $FieldValue[0]....
}
```

...but still, it gets the whole XML object as the field value. I wanted it to extract the value only not the whole object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All simple xml objects are iteratable. Basically think of any object as a set, and some set's just happen to contain one object.

To extract your value do this

```
foreach($title as $item)
{
   $list_of_titles = (string) $item;
}
print_r($list_of_titles);
```

So basically I typecast every item into a string from an object.